# Form not hitting action in controller when submitted with Ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax, form-submit

I've looked at other related posts on how to do the code but I still can't get it working

I'm trying to use Ajax to submit a form but the action in the controller is never hit when the button is clicked.

```
$('#sendCodeForm').submit(function (e) {
            var form = $('sendCodeForm')[0]; 
            var formData = new FormData(form);                
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SendResetCode", "Home")',
                    type: 'post',
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    data: formdata,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status == "success") {
                            $("#successMessage").append('Reset code has been sent to');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

<form id="sendCodeForm">
    <label for="email">EMAIL ADDRESS</label>
    <input asp-for="username" id="username" type="email" placeholder="your@email.com" /><br>
    <button type="submit" id="sendCodeBtn">Send Code</button>
</form>
```

I had originally created the form using the Ajax tag helpers like below, but had to change to using Ajax in the javascript due to now being able to stop the form redirecting

```
<form asp-controller="" asp-action="" method="post" data-ajax="true" data- 
ajax-method="post" data-ajax-complete="completed">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change your code like below:

```
            $('#sendCodeForm').submit( function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData($('#sendCodeForm')[0]);              
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("SendResetCode", "Home")',
                        type: 'post',
                        cache: false,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        data: formData,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.status == "success") {
                                $("#successMessage").append('Reset code has been sent to');
                            }
                        }
                    });               
            });
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'm assuming it was moving e.preventDefault() above declaring the form data..